# How to shift position of colorbar in 3d plot

Tags: matlab, plot, position, scatter-plot, colorbar

I'm displaying a 3D scatterplot, but label on the z-axis is getting overlapped by the color bar. How can I shift the color bar a desired number of pixels to the right or left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findobj`to get an handle to the colorbar, query its current position via `get` and then modify according to your needs and change it using `set`:

```
h = findobj('tag', 'Colorbar');
pos = get(h, 'position')

% modify pos according to your needs

set(h, 'position', pos)
```